# ImmutableJS update List

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

What is the reason behind this code working

```
  return state.update(action.id, function(item) {
    return {id: item.id, title: item.title, duration: item.duration - 1 };
  });
```

and this one that does not work?

```
  return state.update(action.id, function(item) {
    item.duration = item.duration - 1;
    return item;
  });
```

What is the main difference?

Comment: Something inside the current initialState. Suppose it is:

const initialState = new List([
    {id: 0, title: 'Take Shower', duration: 15},
    {id: 1, title: 'Pick Coffe and Sandwich', duration: 10},
    {id: 1, title: 'Brushing teeth', duration: 10}]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImmitableJS's List is not "deeply immutable". `item` is a reference. For you to end up with a new List reference after this operation (and your React components to know something changed) the List references themselves need to change, not just data inside the objects referenced by `item`s.

The reason your first example works is that you are dropping a reference from the List and adding a new one, meaning you get a new List (different reference).

The second example does not alter the references themselves, just the data in the objects, thus you won't get a new List reference.

You could initialize this List by doing a `Immutable.fromJS()` to get your initial List instance. This one is going to create a "deeply immutable" List that will behave like you expect it to in your second example.

Try this ([here's the fiddle for it](https://jsfiddle.net/bzdampr8/1/)):

```
var list = Immutable.List([ {id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3} ]);

var deepList = Immutable.fromJS([ {id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3} ]);

var mutatedList1 = list.update(0, function(item) {
    item.id = 'x';
    return item;
});

var mutatedList2 = list.update(0, function(item) {
    return {id: 'x' };
});

var mutatedList3 = deepList.update(0, function(item) {
    return {id: 'x' };
});


console.log(list.get(0), mutatedList1.get(0), list.get(0) === mutatedList1.get(0), list === mutatedList1);
console.log(list.get(0), mutatedList2.get(0), list === mutatedList2);
console.log(deepList === mutatedList3);
```

With this output:

```
Object {id: "x"} Object {id: "x"} true true
Object {id: "x"} Object {id: "x"} false
false
```

For React to know your list changed the comparison has to be `false`.

Comment: Thanks. Really helpful :)